# flutter new version error. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'

Tags: flutter, dart

I got error. The operator '[]' isn't defined for the type 'Object? Function()'.
How can I solve this error?
this is my code:
If this is not enough, I add the code.

```
Widget sss(BuildContext context) {
return StreamBuilder<QuerySnapshot>(
  stream: FirebaseFirestore.instance
      .collection('게시판')
      .orderBy('id', descending: true) 
      .snapshots(),
  builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot<QuerySnapshot> snapshot) {
    if (snapshot.hasError) return new Text('Error: ${snapshot.error}');
    switch (snapshot.connectionState) {
      case ConnectionState.waiting:
        return new Text('Loading...');
      default:
        return new ListView(
          children: snapshot.data!.docs.map((DocumentSnapshot docs) {
            return new Column(
              children: <Widget>[
                SizedBox(
                  height: 70,
                  child: new ListTile(
                      title: new Text(docs.data!['제목']),     // <= error
                      subtitle: new Text(docs.data!['내용']),  // <= error
                      onTap: () {
                        onMove(docs.data!['제목'], docs.data!['내용']); //<=error
                      }),
                ),
                Divider(
                  thickness: 1.0,
                )
              ],
            );
          }).toList(),
        );
      }
    },
  );
 }
}


class DataBase {
FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;
String collection = '게시판';
void add(String title, String content, String date_time) {
  firestore.collection('카운트').doc('카운트').get().then((DocumentSnapshot ds) {
    
      firestore.collection(collection).doc('${ds.data!['카운트']}).set(    <= error
     
      {'제목': title, '내용': content, '날짜': date_time, 'id': ds.data!['카운트']}); 
        // <= error
      int id = ds.data!['카운트'] + 1; <= error
      cntupdate(id);
  });
}

void cntupdate(int _id) {
  firestore.collection('카운트').doc('카운트').update({'id': _id, '카운트': _id});
}

void update(int _id, String title, String content) {
  firestore
      .collection(collection)
      .doc('$_id')
      .update({'제목': title, '내용': content});
}

 void delete(int _id) {
   firestore.collection(collection).doc('$_id').delete();
  } 
}
```

I got error at ['제목'], ['내용'] and ['카운트'].

I think that this error happens because flutter updates.

I think I need to know there can be String.

How can I solve this error?

Answer (score 0):

That error has nothing to do with a new version of anything.

In this snippet, `docs` refers to a `DocumentSnapshot`:

```
new Text(docs.data!['제목'])
```

While `DocumentSnapshot` has a member called `data`, it is a *method*, not a property. So you need to *call* it:

```
new Text(docs.data()['제목']!)
```

Please note that you should probably find a way to get rid of the `!` operators you sprinkle around your code, they are a clear sign that your code is cheating on null-safety. You have not solved the problem, you have just told your compiler to not bother you with it. But that is another problem for another day.

Comment: Thank you! You were right. I change the code. But, new error that you said happens.       The method '[]' can't be unconditionally invoked because the receiver can be 'null'.  Now, I will find how this error is solved.